# How to get average values from dictionary looking values using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

my dataframe looks like this:

```
id            value
a       0:3,1:0,2:0,3:4
a       0:0,1:0,2:2,3:0
a       0:0,1:5,2:4,3:0
```

I want to write a query to get average values of keys in column value?

So for example for `0:3,1:0,2:0,3:4` it must be `(0+0+0+3+3+3+3)/7 = 1.71`.

For `0:0,1:0,2:2,3:0` it must be `(2+2)/2=2`.

For `0:0,1:5,2:4,3:0` it must be `(1+1+1+1+1+2+2+2+2)/9 = 1.44`.

So desired result is:

```
id            value
a              1.71
a              2.00
a              1.44
```

How to do that? Are there sql functions to get this result?

Comment: I doubt SQL can do it. You could write a stored procedure, but SQL is a poor language choice for this kind of operation. Best/easiest done in app layer.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: is the number of keys variable?  if so, what's the maximum number there could be?

Comment: you show `a` as the id for all rows; is there a primary key or other unique constraint?

Comment: @ysth yeah there can be id column values other than "a"

Answer (score 0):

With some combination of `split`'s, `transform`s and `repeat` you can achieve your goal:

```sql
WITH dataset(id, value) AS (
    values ('a', '0:3,1:0,2:0,3:4'),
        ('a', '0:0,1:0,2:2,3:0'),
        ('a', '0:0,1:5,2:4,3:0')
)

SELECT id,
    reduce(arr, 0.0, (s, x)->s + x, s->s) / cardinality(arr)
FROM(
        SELECT *,
            flatten(
                transform(
                    transform(
                        split(value, ','),
                        s->split(s, ':')
                    ),
                    arr->repeat(
                        cast(arr [ 1 ] as INTEGER),
                        cast(arr [ 2 ] as INTEGER)
                    )
                )
            ) as arr
        FROM dataset
    )
```

Output:

| id | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1.7142857142857142 |
| a | 2.0 |
| a | 1.4444444444444444 |

Note:

Outer select can be substituted with `array_average` but I used the select because Athena's version of Presto does not support it.

### Update

Another version which can be more performant:

```sql
SELECT id,
    reduce(
        arr,
        CAST(ROW(0.0, 0) AS ROW(sum DOUBLE, count INTEGER)),
        (s, r)->CAST(
            ROW(r.num * r.count + s.sum, s.count + r.count) AS ROW(sum DOUBLE, count INTEGER)
        ),
        s->IF(s.count = 0, NULL, s.sum / s.count)
    )
FROM(
        SELECT *,
            transform(
                split(value, ','),
                s->CAST(
                    ROW(
                        CAST(split(s, ':') [ 1 ] AS DOUBLE),
                        (CAST(split(s, ':') [ 2 ] AS INTEGER))
                    ) AS ROW(num DOUBLE, count INTEGER)
                )
            ) as arr
        FROM dataset
    )
```

Comment: thx, what do you mean by "Outer select can be substituted with array_average"? which part can be substituted?

Comment: it returned ne error "PrestoQueryError(type=INTERNAL_ERROR, name=GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR, message="SignatureBinder.iterativeSolve does not converge after 4 iterations.""

Comment: @skulldoger by outer select i mean outer select. i.e.  `SELECT id, reduce(..) FROM()` can be removed and inner select changed to `SELECT *, array_average(faltten(....))`

Comment: @skulldoger please see the update. As for your error - maybe [this](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/14066) can help

Answer (score 0):

See this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfb9cbcd96644cd8920ac068e924755c)

code:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `avg_dict`(s varchar(100))
BEGIN
  SET @result = CONCAT('SELECT (', replace(replace(s, ":","*"),",","+"), ')/(',regexp_replace(s,",?[0-9]:","+"),')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @result;
  EXECUTE stmt  ;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

results:

| stmt | output |
| --- | --- |
| `CALL avg_dict("0:3,1:0,2:0,3:4");` | 1.1743 |
| `CALL avg_dict("0:0,1:0,2:2,3:0");` | 2.0000 |
| `CALL avg_dict("0:0,1:5,2:4,3:0");` | 1.4444 |